# Best way to fade and loop through a set of divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say I have the following divs:

```
<div class="a">You are funny.</div>
<div class="b">You are smart.</div>
<div class="c">You are cool.</div>
```

What is the best way to show `div.a` for 5 seconds, then fade out and fade in `div.b` for 5 seconds and then to `div.c` and then back to `div.a` and continue looping for an infinite amount of time?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use an array of values and loop thru them.

```
var div = $('div').hide(),
    news = ['news1', 'news2', 'news3'],
    count = 0;

function changeNews() {
    div.fadeIn().delay(500).fadeOut(function() {
        changeNews();
    }).text(news[count++])
    if (count == news.length) {
        count = 0;
    }
}
changeNews();
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/qJa3h/

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. You are editing the text of the same <div> element three times. The OP asked how one can cycle through showing three separate <div>s.

Answer (score 2):

How about a jQuery plugin? I haven't tested it but something like this should get you started:

```
(function($) {

    $.fn.keepFadingToNext = function(options) {
        var defaults = {
            duration: 5000
        };

        var settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

        var original = this;

        var doAnimations = function(element) {
            element.fadeIn(settings.duration, function() {
                element.fadeOut(settings.duration, function() {
                    var next = element.next();

                    if (next.length === 0) {
                        next = original;
                    }

                    doAnimations(next);
                });
            });
        };

        doAnimations(original);

        return original;
    };

})(jQuery)

$('.a').keepFadingToNext();

// or
$('.a').keepFadingToNext({ duration: 3000 });
```

Comment: Cool thank you -- but how will it know to go to `.b`, then `.c` and then back to `.a`?

Comment: I see that I didn't make that so clear in my original post -- but I have updated it -- sorry!

Comment: Updated. See if this will give you a start.

Comment: +1 Thanks, I hadn't seen JQuery plugins. That adds a whole new meaning to my idea of ugly syntax.